# PHP exceptions: where to put dynamic data?

Tags: php, exception

I'm in the process of rewriting the error handling of PEAR's [Text_LanguageDetect](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_LanguageDetect) to exceptions and don't really know what to do with dynamic data in exceptions:

```
throw new Text_LanguageDetect_Exception(
    'Language database does not exist.',
    Text_LanguageDetect_Exception::DB_NOT_FOUND
);
```

Here I'd like to include the file name that was tried to be opened, but the question is *where* to put it:

1. `Language database /path/to/file.ext does not exist.`
2. `Language database "/path/to/file.ext" does not exist.`
3. `Language database does not exist: /path/to/file.ext`
4. `Language database does not exist: "/path/to/file.ext"`

1+2 are proper english sentences, while 3+4 make it easy to grep for the message in the code. Also, extracting the file name with code is easier in 3+4.

Which one should I use, any why?

---

Another question is: Where should I put the file name?

When I put it the exception message, it may give attackers information about the file structure on the server if he sees the message. Without the file name, it's harder to debug.

Comment: since error messages should be disabled on production servers i dont see the issue about attackers gaining insight on the file structure. its not a component writer's responsibility to anticipate misconfiguration of the component's users. Regarding which message I prefer: 4. apart from that, its a poll type question and not that suited for SO I guess.

Comment: Use `sprintf()` so you can more easily decouple and change things while keeping the code clean. Next to that, check the style across the whole component so you do it always similar which will reduce the learning curve. Provide all information that is useful to a user of your API to deal with exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one write good error messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194537/how-does-one-write-good-error-messages)

Comment: It's not a poll. I'd like to get answers *why* I should use an option, not who uses what.

Comment: @cweiske It's SO. They wont give you reason :) I'd pick 4 because it's easiest to grok for me (which is as good as any other reason). I'd probably add an "at" to it though to make it a full sentence: *Language database does not exist at "/path/to/file.ext"*. Also, I might add a suggestion for a solution, like *Check the file path and make sure its readable* or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use message format that seems more readable to you. It's not a good practice to rely on exception message in the code. If you need to do it, you should probably subclass the exception instead.

Second question: you should not display detailed errors to users in production environment, so I don't see including filename as a problem.

Answer (score -1):

When throwing exceptions it's helpful to have an envrionment variable that tells your code whether you're in development or live. This can be set where you have other system wide settings stored.

If it is set to development then you output errors that make debugging easier, if it's set to live then output errors that are helpful to the end user (or no error at all and handle it gracefully), this will then not offer any information to would be attackers.

Comment: This does not answer his questions.

Comment: Not suitable for a general purpose library. Pear is a repository of such.